# please, how do I get over "int() argument must be a string, a byte-like object or a real number, not a 'NoneType'" error in my code?

Tags: python, html, django

`<h1>This is food box page</h1><br><br>`

```
`<image src= "{% static 'food_app/image1.jpeg' %}">`
<h2>{{food_box1.0}}</h2>
<h3>{{food_box1.1}}</h3>
<button type= "button"><strong>EAT ME!</strong></button><br><br>
<form action="{% url 'food_app:price' %}" method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
<label for="price in packs"><strong>Price in packs</strong></label>
`<input type="text" id="price in packs" name="price1" placeholder="Enter number between 20 and 
enter code h 500">` 
<h1>{{new_price}}</h1>
<button type= "button"><strong>EAT ME!</strong></button>
</form>
```

`<br>`
`<br>`

```
<image src= "{% static 'food_app/image2.jpeg' %}">
<h2>{{food_box2.0}}</h2>
<h3>{{food_box2.1}}</h3>
<button type= "button"><strong>EAT ME!</strong></button><br><br>
<form action="{% url 'food_app:price' %}" method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
<label for="price in packs"><strong>Price in packs</strong></label>
`<input type="text" id="price in packs" name="price2" placeholder="Enter number between 20 and 
500">`
<h1>{{new_price2}}</h1>
<button type= "button"><strong>EAT ME!</strong></button>            
</form>
```

Python

```
if request.method == "POST":


price_pack_box = int(request.GET.get("price1"))
if price_pack_box >= 20 and price_pack_box <= 500:
food = Food.objects.get(pk=40)
food_price = food.food_price
total_price1 = price_pack_box*food_price
elif price_pack_box < 20:
messages.info(request, "number input too small!")
return redirect('food_app:foodbox')
elif price_pack_box > 500:
messages.info(request, "number input too large!")
return redirect('food_app:foodbox')
print(total_price1)

 `elif request.method == "POST":`
 `price_pack_box = int(request.POST.get("price2"))`
     `if price_pack_box >= 20 and price_pack_box <= 500:`
     `food = Food.objects.get(pk=41)`   
     `food_price = food.food_price`
      total_price2 = price_pack_box*food_price
      elif price_pack_box < 20:
      messages.info(request, "number input too small!")
      return redirect('food_app:foodbox')
      elif price_pack_box > 500:
      messages.info(request, "number input too large!")
      return redirect('food_app:foodbox')
      print(total_price2)
```

`my_dict = {'new_price':total_price1,'new_price2':total_price2,'new_price3':total_price3}` 
`return render(request, 'food_app/price.html', context=my_dict)`

This is my first time posting question, pls, do not mind my error

Comment: Well apparently `request.POST` has no` price1` and/or `price2`, so `request.POST.get('price1')` returns `None`. This is one of the many reasons why you should use a Django form...

Comment: Ooh, I thought django forms works only for authentication... I will learn it or could you help mee with resources that focuses only on django forms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume this is what your HTML file looks like. This file contains two forms (`<form>`) which would send **POST** requests to your python code.

> I IDs and hidden inputs to each form so you can identify each of them in your code

```html
<h1>This is food box page</h1><br><br>
<image src= "{% static 'food_app/image1.jpeg' %}"/>
<h2>{{food_box1.0}}</h2>
<h3>{{food_box1.1}}</h3>
<button type= "button"><strong>EAT ME!</strong></button>
<br><br>

<form action="{% url 'food_app:price' %}" method="POST" id="form1">
    {% csrf_token %}

    <label for="price in packs"><strong>Price in packs</strong></label>
    <input type="hidden" name="form" value="form1">
    <input type="text" id="price in packs" name="price1" placeholder="Enter number between 20 and 500">
    <h1>{{new_price}}</h1>
    <button type= "button"><strong>EAT ME!</strong></button>
</form>
<br> <br>
<image src= "{% static 'food_app/image2.jpeg' %}">
<h2>{{food_box2.0}}</h2>
<h3>{{food_box2.1}}</h3>
<button type= "button"><strong>EAT ME!</strong></button><br><br>
<form action="{% url 'food_app:price' %}" method="POST" id="form2">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <label for="price in packs"><strong>Price in packs</strong></label>
    <input type="hidden" name="form" value="form2">
    <input type="text" id="price in packs" name="price2" placeholder="Enter number between 20 and 500">
    <h1>{{new_price2}}</h1>
    <button type= "button"><strong>EAT ME!</strong></button>            
</form>
```

The first issue here is the you have 2 forms, this means your request can only contain `price1` **or** `price2` but never both of them, so you have to make provision for that.

Another issue is that the form can be submitted without providing any value.
This means that `price1` and `price2` can be `None` which is sometimes not a good idea.

Lastly, you set the type of `price1` and `price2` to "text":

```html
<input type="text" id="price in packs" name="price1" placeholder="Enter number between 20 and 500">
...
<input type="text" id="price in packs" name="price2" placeholder="Enter number between 20 and 500">
```

Which means if someone submitted "apple" the form would accept it. You should set the type to "number" to accept only numbers.

As an improvement, you can also set `min="20"`(minimum price) and `max="500"`(maximum price) to save you the stress of having to write this:

```
if price_pack_box >= 20 and price_pack_box <= 500:
    ...
else:
    ...
```

Change

Refactor your python code to this

```py
if request.method == "POST":
    if request.POST["form"] == "form1":
        price_pack_box = int(request.POST["price1"])
        food = Food.objects.get(pk=40)
    elif request.POST["form"] == "form2":
        price_pack_box = int(request.POST["price2"])
        food = Food.objects.get(pk=41)
    food_price = food.food_price
    total_price1 = price_pack_box*food_price
    print(total_price1)
```

> You code still needs a lot of refactoring bro, else you'll keep running into errors

Comment: Thanks you very much... But could you expatiate a little more? What's is the function of "0", and what do you mean by "incase it is not supplied un the form"? How do I supply it inside the form? Thanks so much

Comment: Thank you very much bro. I really appreciate your help..i will try it out this way. Plus, I know my code needs a lot of refactor cus I didn't use django forms.. I still need to learn how to use them.

Comment: Yeah anytime bruh.

Comment: Thank you very much, bro... The code runs perfectly now...

Comment: Hello bro, please I have been trying to tag you in a post but I can not. Is there a way I can share the link to you through whatsapp?